# Problem with sockets, recv function. Python

Tags: python, sockets, server

> So in other words it's just stuck after 1st response from the browser.
> I'm new to socket programming, but here is stupid question, do I need
> to close client socket after the response from the server is sent? In
> `handleData` after `self.client.send()`. Or what could be the reason
> of this behaviour?  Tried to use select here to make it asynchronous
> but it didn't help. Same issue. After I get request from the client
> with headers, I go to the next iteration of the loop, exactly to the
> `recv()` and it is stuck. The client is not sending info anymore and
> doesn't show the info that is sent from the server. In this example it
> is "Info/Message was retrieved!".

```
P.S. DEFAULT_ENCODING = "utf-8"
DEFAULT_CLIENTS_AMOUNT = 5
SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PORT = 8080
```

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, socket_family: int = socket.AF_INET, socket_type: int = socket.SOCK_STREAM, ip_address: str = SERVER_IP, port: int = SERVER_PORT):
        self.addr: Tuple[str, int] = ip_address, port
        self.serv_heart: socket.socket = socket.socket(socket_family, socket_type)
        self.client: Optional[socket.socket] = None

    def _launchSyncServer(self, clients: int = DEFAULT_CLIENTS_AMOUNT):
        print("Starting server...")
        self.serv_heart.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
        self.serv_heart.bind(self.addr)
        self.serv_heart.listen(clients)
        print(f"Server started at {str(self.addr)}")
        print(f"Visible: http://{self.addr[0]}:{self.addr[1]}")

    def _acceptConnections(self):
        client_socket, client_addr = self.serv_heart.accept()
        print(f"Client connected from {str(client_addr)}")
        self.client = client_socket

    def _handleData(self):
        while True:
            rawData: str = self.client.recv(128).decode(DEFAULT_ENCODING)
            if not rawData:
                self.client.close()
                break

            self.client.send("Info/Message was retrieved!".encode(DEFAULT_ENCODING))

        self.client.close()

    def serverLoop(self, clients: int = DEFAULT_CLIENTS_AMOUNT):
        self._launchSyncServer(clients=clients)
        while True:
          self._acceptConnections()
          self._handleData()
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's just stuck after 1st response from the browser.

Your server doesn't implement HTTP nor any other browser protocol, so a browser is not an appropriate client for it; better use something like `nc localhost 8080`.

> do I need to close client socket after the response from the server is sent?

That depends on how you want the communication to be conducted. If you want the client to only send one message, you can close the server's connection right after responding. If you want the client to be able to send multiple messages, the server as it is is prepared for that, and the client needs to indicate that it's finished by closing its socket or at least shutting down writing.
Note that in general, you can't be sure that a message is reveived in whole with a single `recv` call - it might be split and returned piece by piece through several calls of `recv`.